# Сокращенная надпись if

Tags: php

Всем привет, есть такой вот код в PHP

```
<?
if ($lang==eng) {echo $capital['title_eng']} else {$capital['title_ru']}
?>
```

Как можно сокращенно ее написать?

Comment: `echo lang == foo ? bar : baz;` почитайте про тернарный оператор http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: обращу еще внимание, что `eng` у вас вряд ли является константой, следовательно в логах имеете нотисы на каждый вызов

Comment: ну смотри, по моему если оператор if принемает только 1 строку, то фигурные скобки не нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<? echo ($lang==eng) ? $capital['title_eng'] : $capital['title_ru']; ?>
```

Comment: Скобки вокруг условия не обязательны: `<?= $lang == 'en' ? $capital['title_eng'] : $capital['title_ru'] ?>`

Comment: это наверное пример как не надо делать, шорт теги и тенарник которые не рокемендуют использовать. При том eng не строка

Answer (score 2):

Наверно, у Вас в коде есть ещё много мест, где Вы проверяете подобным образом язык и выбираете правильную строку. Поэтому, лучше завести переменную, где будет хранится язык (собственно, она уже есть и использовать прямо так

```
echo $capital['title_'.$lang];
```

или переделать систему хранения строк. Я бы хранил бы массивы под каждый язык отдельно. В этом случае будет одна строка выбора правильного языка, а дальше все будет вот так

```
echo $capital['title'];
```

Comment: А если будет не rus или eng а kz которого у него нет  ?

Comment: @Даниил это валидировать надо не в шаблоне при выводе какой то конкретной надписи, а на уровне целиком приложения, установив язык по умолчанию.

Comment: @Даниил Вот поэтому я и написал, что должен быть один массив. И отдельно функция, которая этот массив получает/загружает. И она уже должна озаботиться тем, что бы все нужные переменные были выставлены.